# Dynamic UI Theme

Tags: android

I am working in an application for Android. My application will use my server for the data push and pull. I want to provide a dashboard where user can draw its custom theme for Android application. When user will finalized its design a layout xml and images will be placed its user area. Android application will download these files and update its ui. 
Where will we put our layout and images files in running application?

I have a activity class in server can it be include in running Android application or not?

Answer (score 0):

The XML files android uses to render interfaces are optimized/compiled.

[How can I write android binary XML from Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624063/how-can-i-write-android-binary-xml-from-android-app)